# Unit testing + Mocking eBPF programs in python incl emulating kernel to user-space interactions

Tags: python, unit-testing, linux-kernel

So I need to get some mocking+testing done on a very specific kind of python code: it is an eBPF(Berkely packet filter) program using python, which in essence runs a C program in kernel space through a python script via the BPF Compiler Collection BCC
eg code:

```
from bcc import BPF
# define BPF program
prog = """
int hello(void *ctx) {
    bpf_trace_printk("Hello, World!\\n");
    return 0;
}
"""
# load BPF program
b = BPF(text=prog)
b.attach_kprobe(event=b.get_syscall_fnname("clone"), fn_name="hello")
# header
print("%-18s %-16s %-6s %s" % ("TIME(s)", "COMM", "PID", "MESSAGE"))
# format output
while 1:
    try:
        (task, pid, cpu, flags, ts, msg) = b.trace_fields()
    except ValueError:
        continue
    print("%-18.9f %-16s %-6d %s" % (ts, task, pid, msg))
```

I want to now write tests for the C and the Python code without the 2 interfering (I would even be satisfied with some basic python unit testing). Any & all possible approaches to the problem are welcome, or even a general direction to look for info on this kind of testing, really just looking to address the following concerns:
**Can I easily mock the kernel interactions when testing the python code?
Can I emulate a message coming from the kernel to user-space?
Can I test a message that’s just larger or just smaller than the expected message size?**

I tried looking into the topic for days, to no avail so even pointing me in the right direction would be greatly appreciated...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out there is no quick way to really get into the testing of the C code in a basic way like you would using pytest to test the python logic. However if you absolutely need solid testing done then [browsing through here](https://github.com/iovisor/bcc/blob/88b5edbdc98a50dedf9a911b8f1ab5a63c574767/tests/python/test_trace2.py) and making sense of how BCC does their version of "unit testing" may be of help...